# generating a set of sets that appear in every set

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I have an array of arrays of things

```
typedef std::vector<thing> group;

std::vector<group> groups;
```

things could be compared like so

```
int comparison(thing a, thing b);
```

where the return value is `0, 1 or 2`

`0` means that the things are not alike

`1` means that they are alike and `a` is more specific or equal to `b`

`2` means that they are alike and `b` is more specific or equal to `a`

and I am looking for a function that would return me a group that contains all things that appear in every group.

```
std::getgroup(groups.begin(), groups.end(), myComparisonFunction);
```

the problem is I have no idea what this function may be called, if it does even exist, or what the closest thing to it would be.

Comment: You mean a function to return every thing of `std::vector<std::vector<thing>>` into a single `std::vector<thing>`?

Comment: so if a thing appears inside all the groups then it will be added to the group that `getgroup` returns

Comment: 2 downvotes so far, i don't mind but if you are downvoting because the question is confusing please say something because i can and will edit it

Comment: I haven't downvoted yet, but I suspect that not showing any code of what you tried so far is a big part of it.

Comment: Why is a `group` a `vector` rather than an `unordered_set` ?

Comment: i used set in the title because i was trying to make the title concise but that may have been an error - you should be able to use any iterable container

Comment: @ChatterOne the problem is I was looking for a function in the standard library that did something like this or a response like 'this doesn't exist'

Comment: Again - Why is a group a `vector` rather than an `unordered_set` ?

Comment: In my opinion you should at least add the code which describes the thing element. I think the function you want to create depends on that.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, what you want is an intersection. Luckily, there is `std::set_intersection` which almost does what you need. Here's a simple example on `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. You can easily change it to work with your `thing`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> getGroup(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& groups) {

    std::vector<int> group;
    std::vector<int> temp = groups[0];
    std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());

    for ( unsigned i = 1; i < groups.size(); ++i ) {

        group = std::vector<int>();

        std::vector<int> temp2 = groups[i];
        std::sort(temp2.begin(), temp2.end());

        std::set_intersection(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(),
                              temp.begin(), temp.end(),
                              std::back_inserter(group));


        temp = group;

    }

    return group;

}

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> groups = { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                                             {1, 2, 3,    5, 6, 7, 8,    10},
                                             {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                                             {1,    3, 4, 5, 6,       9, 10},
                                             {1, 2,          6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                                             {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} };

    for ( auto g : getGroup(groups) )
        std::cout << g << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

This will print:

> 1
>   6
>   10

Comment: `std::set_intersection` expects that its argument ranges are sorted.

Comment: The problem is say `thing a` has value of `apple` and `thing b` has value of `fruit` and both are in separate groups. Then I want to be given a group with `apple` in it, since it is a fruit and an apple so it appears in both groups. Not sure how to do this in the comparison function

Comment: @xskxzr Sorry, totally forgot that detail :P I just fixed it.